# Can boost filesystem change the read-only attribute of a file?

Tags: boost, attributes, filesystems

Is there a way to change the attribute of a file from read-only to read-write using the boost filesystem library? If not, what is the next-best way to do this on Windows (using Microsoft's C++)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't find how to do that in the boost library. But you can do it using Windows API:

```
SetFileAttributes(lpFileName, GetFileAttributes(lpFileName) & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
```

See [SetFileAttributes Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365535(VS.85).aspx) and [GetFileAttributes Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) for more info.

Comment: To make the file read-only use the following code: `SetFileAttributes(lpFileName, GetFileAttributes(lpFileName) | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);`

Answer (score 2):

The following worked with Boost 1.55 on Windows:

```
permissions(file_path, add_perms|owner_write|group_write|others_write);
```

Comment: Seems to be not available on older Boost Versions (e.g. V 1.45).